# PHP - search for a file within the current folder and subfolders

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm trying to retrieve path of a file in PHP but i'm currently stuck. I have a folder structure like this:

```
- folder 1/
- folder 2/
    - subfolder 2.1/
    - subfolder 2.2/
        - subfolder 2.2.1/
        - subfolder 2.2.2/
            - targetFile.txt
            - script1.php
            - script2.php
            - .htaccess
        - file1.php
        - file2.php
        - file3.php
        - getFile.php
        .htaccess
- Folder 3/
- Folder 4/
...
```

I wish to get a `relative` path of `targetFile.txt` when running `getFile.php` script. The target file is always within a folder which is located in the same parent folder as the getFile.php. In case above the relative path should print out:

```
subfolder 2.2.2/targetFile.txt
```

Here is what i have so far:

```
$dir = getcwd(); // Getting the current working dir
$files = scandir($dir); // Get all files and folders within the working dir
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file = 'targetFile.txt') { // Look for a file that matches the targeted file name
        echo dirname($file);
    }
}
```

The code above isn't working properly as i don't get a relative path for the target file.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by **isn't working properly** ?

Comment: Just to be sure I understood it right: Can you mention the directory your `getFile.php` is in?

Comment: @Twinfriends The getFile.php is always within the same parent directory. The problem is that the subdirectory of the targetFile.txt is changing so i need to start the path relative to the getFile.php. Hope i understood your question.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz The code above just returns dots...

Comment: @g5wx So in your case the getFile.php is in the folder subfolder 2.2, or subfolder 2.2.2 ? That difficult to name the directory? If someone asks you for the foldername, simply say the foldername.. don't start talking again about subfolders / parentfolders. That will only confuse people since in your presented folderstructure you've around 4 levels of depth.

Comment: Yes, In subfolder 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php
    $dir = getcwd(); // Getting the current working dir
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'));
    // Get all files and folders within the working dir

    $files = [];
    foreach ($iterator as $filename => $file) {
        $path = pathinfo($filename);
        if ($path['basename'] == 'targetFile.txt') {
            echo $path['dirname'] .'<br />';
            //echo $path['dirname'], "\n";
            //echo $path['basename'], "\n";
            //echo $path['extension'], "\n";
            //echo $path['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
        }
        $files[] = $filename;
    }
    //asort($files);
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($files);die;
?>
```

**More info:**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Comment: While you fixed the `if` statement problem, the code still won't work. The problem: " The target file is always within a folder which is located in the same parent folder as the getFile.php." - scandir would be able to find the folder where the script is in, but it won't scan that folder again for the file.

Comment: Chandra, this echoes nothing :/

Comment: Yep, works well. I've stripped out dot and a backslash from the string: `echo str_replace('.\\', '', $path['dirname']);` and removed `$files[]` array. Thanks!

Comment: p.s. I'm guessing `$dir = getcwd()` and `$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);` is also not needed and commented out code :)

Comment: You can comment this line: `$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);`

Comment: Update like this `$dir = getcwd(); // Getting the current working dir
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di);`